# Why can't I make my question a community wiki?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

Am I missing something?

I can't seem to find an option to make my [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31/essential-reading-learning-resources-for-the-code-reviewer) a community wiki.

Comment: hmmm ... answers can be made wiki.  I had this idea that questions could too.  Am I imagining things?

Comment: i think SE changed that recently. But if have you more than 4 editors I think it automagically becomes a wiki

Comment: @cbrulak That needs more edits, but yes, it becomes CW after some edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only moderators can mark a question as Community Wiki.  The correct approach, if you think a question (yours or someone else's) should be CW, is to flag it for moderator attention with a note asking for conversion to CW.